# How do game and program developers solve the pinyin input problem in their programs

Tags: pinyin

I always wondered about this and never felt the need to ask because I figured I would figure it out on my own. But I can't find an answer.

All of these games, especially multiplayer games, we people play in the West, use keyboard input. Since Sougou and Google / MS Pinyin IME are strictly OS tailored....how is it done in games? Do they still use Pinyin as input? Does every game have their own program? It sounds like a massive investment. What about messenger apps etc.

I'm interested to know how this is dealt with, maybe a question for people who live in China. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure IMEs are compatible with program as long as the program has supported Chinese fonts.

Comment: You're asking the mechanism of IMEs in an OS. This question may be more suitable to be asked in http://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a programming question better suited for www.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

This question does not belong in Chinese language section, nevertheless.

What you're talking are Chinese language input tools. There is actually nothing to solve here for game developers. Any game user can use **Google pinyin, Sogou, Baidu** input tools in a full screen application for Chinese input. A user types Chinese words in pinyin and gets a list of corresponding words. Some games may independently implement different language input switches via os IME API:

[image: picture]

On Linux machine a user may use **scim, fcitx or ibus** input tools which work in the similar manner.

Comment: What game is this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better to know how computer distinguish words end user input.

Here is a general idea,

Computer could only know true and false, 1 and 0, and all the words would be 1 and 0 in the end.

English words and Chinese words are the same for the computer basically.

So we have to make computer know what does 'A' mean, and what does '我' mean.
There are different character encoding tables for almost all of known languages, they help computer to recognize different languages.

Refer to wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Hope it can help you.
Regards